# My LI are duplicating every time I submit my form with javascript

Tags: javascript

My initial post was set to put put the minimal code I could.  It looks like I needed more of my code for this example to work.  This time I have added all of the code in hope that you will be able to see where I am going wrong.  Thank you.

```js
document.querySelector('.add-task').addEventListener('click', onClick);

function onClick(addTask) {

  var taskInput = document.getElementById('taskId');

  document.querySelector('form.taskForm').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // create element
    const li = document.createElement('li');

    // add classname
    li.className = "list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center";

    // create text node and append (*** need to change new task to form data)
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(taskInput.value));

    // append li as child to ul
    document.querySelector('ul.list-group').appendChild(li);


  })

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Task List</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Header Start -->
  <div class="container border border-light">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-10">
        <h1 class='headTaskList'>Task List</h1>
        <h2 class='headSub'>New Task</h2>
        <form class='taskForm'>
          <input id="taskId" class="userTaskInput form-control form-control-lg formNewTask" type="text" placeholder="Walk the dog">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary add-task">Submit</button>

        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Header Finish-->

  <!-- Task List Container-->
  <div class="container border border-light">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-10">
        <h3 class='tasklistTitle'>Task List</h3>
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            Cras justo odio
            <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">X</span>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            Dapibus ac facilisis in
            <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">X</span>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            Morbi leo risus
            <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">X</span>
          </li>

        </ul>
        <button type="button" class="clearBtn btn btn-primary" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false">
                        Clear Task
                      </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- Task List Complete-->


  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I am missing something here. I am building a task list. Every time I input something in the task list, it starts duplicating.  For example.  A BB CCC DDDD EEEEE

Looking for a way to prevent this.

I have added this link so you can see the issue: jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=4jhnVboliB

```js
document.querySelector('.add-task').addEventListener('click', onClick);

function onClick(addTask) {

  var taskInput = document.getElementById('taskId');

  document.querySelector('form.taskForm').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // create element
    const li = document.createElement('li');

    // add classname
    li.className = "list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center";

    // create text node and append (*** need to change new task to form data)
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(taskInput.value));

    // append li as child to ul
    document.querySelector('ul.list-group').appendChild(li);


  })

}
```

```html
<form class='taskForm'>
  <input id="taskId" class="userTaskInput form-control form-control-lg formNewTask" type="text" placeholder="Walk the dog">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary add-task">Submit</button>
```

Comment: No, it throws an exception: "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null",

Comment: Can you check the jsfiddle link.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Comment: I have added all the code.  I am trying to walk the fine line of putting just the necessary code and not all the code.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You add another form submission listener every time you click the button.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `click` handler which, **every time** the submit button is clicked, adds a `submit` handler (which adds to the list).

So the first time you click the submit button:

1. The click handler adds a submit handler
2. The submit handler adds the list item

The second time you click it:

1. The click handler adds **another** submit handler
2. The first submit handler adds the list item
3. The second submit handler adds the list item

And so on.

Just add a submit handler. Get rid of the click handler that adds the submit handler.

Comment: I seem to be breaking the code. I have removed the click handler, and add the submit handler with no success.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I needed to move

```
 var taskInput = document.getElementById('taskId');

document.querySelector('form.taskForm').addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault()});
```

outside of the click function.

this was the solution that worked for me:

document.querySelector('.add-task').addEventListener('click', onClick);

function onClick(addTask){

// create element
   const li = document.createElement('li');

// add classname
   li.className = "list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center";

// create text node and append (*** need to change new task to form data)
   li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(taskInput.value));

// append li as child to ul
   document.querySelector('ul.list-group').appendChild(li);

};

var taskInput = document.getElementById('taskId');

document.querySelector('form.taskForm').addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault()});